# Loop through all cells except first in each row, and hide row if all cells have specific class

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery, which works like a charm:

```
$('#planCompareTable > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').hasClass('noValue') && $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').hasClass('noValue')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
}
```

I'm looking at a particular table, looping through each row, checking cells 2 and 3 in that row for the class of `noValue`, and hiding the row if that exists. Great.

My issue now is, I don't know how many columns this table will have, but I need to continue to check every column after the first in each row for that class, and hiding the row if & only if ALL cells beyond the first have this class.

I tried updating my 2nd line to `if ($(this).find('td:not(:first)').each(hasClass('noValue')))`, but if it finds ANY cell with the class `noValue`, it will hide the whole row, regardless of the status of other cells in that row.

My assumption is that I need to have a nested each() function here, but I'm not certain how to go about doing this.

Comment: I don't think you need a nested each. Simply count all cells in a row then compare that to the count of cells that have your target class. If the difference is more than 1, hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of `noValue` cells and if its one less than the total cells hide the row.

```js
$('#planCompareTable > tbody > tr').each(function(){
   var $row = $(this);
   var allNoValue = ($row.find("td.noValue").length == ($row.find("td").length-1));
   if(allNoValue) $row.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="planCompareTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row1</td>
      <td class="noValue"></td>
      <td class="noValue"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2</td>
      <td class="noValue"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```